# what is the best way to conect the ffmpeg lib to the MediaCapture API in visual studio?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, ffmpeg, video-streaming

hello community  i will like to use ffmpeg with the MediaCapture API resource. Can i?
the doubt came because ffmpeg command read from a file, or a rtsp etc... 
i will like to use the ffmpeg as a process meaning using a ffmepeg command line.
I am still a rookie in audio video tech.. An example will be great..
thanks

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve that has caused you to look into an external library? Is there something the MediaCapture API can't do for you?

Comment: what i need is to connect the ffmpeg API functions with the capture of the MediaCapture class by the capture buffer. The final issue is to livestream the data in webm format into a kive server.

Comment: It sounds like you need to create your own custom video sink, which can take a stream from the MediaCapture. In it, you'd implement the code to re-encode it (ffmpeg?) and stream it.